# TSql Output From in Update query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to update a table and return some values in the same query, however one of the values to return is located in a linked table

Since sub-queries (which seem perfectly unambiguous to me) aren't allowed in Output clauses I'm trying to write the query using the Output From syntax with a join but this seems to me to produce all sorts of ambiguity

Consider for example the following query:

```
UPDATE tbla SET datecol=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OUTPUT deleted.datecol AS old, inserted.datecol AS new, b.col2
FROM tbla a LEFT JOIN tblb b ON a.bkey=b.bkey
WHERE akey=6
```

How does Sql Server know to what that WHERE clause refers? It seems to me that both the UPDATE and FROM parts of the query both qualify for a WHERE clause, so will that WHERE clause restrict which rows update or which rows appear in the output or both?

In my testing I've also seen Sql Server ask for table identifiers to be added to the WHERE clause in situations that I've been unable to pick out a cause or pattern for, so is the tbla referred to in the UPDATE part of the statement implicitly identified as "a" because I've aliased it as that in the FROM statement? If so is "a" referencing inserted or deleted? And if I hadn't aliased it there which version of the table would tbla.akey refer to?

I've not been able to find any decipherable documentation on exactly how this works, and the messages coming back from SQL Server when I'm testing are only making me more confused

I'd also love to know why the following query isn't allowed as it seems like a faultlessly superior way of doing the same thing, certainly not at all ambiguous and a lot more self explanatory

```
UPDATE tbla SET datecol=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OUTPUT deleted.datecol AS old, inserted.datecol AS new,
    (SELECT TOP(1) b.col2 FROM tblb b WHERE deleted.bkey = b.bkey) AS col2
WHERE akey=6
```

Comment: The WHERE clause belongs to the update! The OUTPUT clause is just to return what was updatet, but afaik it is not possible to use the output like a derived table or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You could write the output to  a table variable and then work with it:

Could look like that in your case:

```
DECLARE @output TABLE
(
    bkey INT,
    datecolold DATETIME,
    datecolnew DATETIME
)

UPDATE tbla SET datecol=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OUTPUT deleted.bkey, deleted.datecol, inserted.datecol INTO @output
WHERE akey=6

SELECT b.col2, o.* FROM @output o INNER JOIN tblb b ON o.bkey = b.bkey
```

Comment: While this is a good solution for the example problem that I came up with, I was really looking to understand the relationship between the UPDATE, OUTPUT, FROM and WHERE clauses, rather than find the solution to an issue I invented to illustrate my confusion. But thanks for posting the clever code, it's a good idea that neatly sidesteps the whole issue

Comment: i know it's exhausting but going through this is never a bad idea: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177523(v=sql.120).aspx